# Passing several type of class in function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I have a enum class:

```
enum Info
{
  TYPE_1,
  TYPE_2
};
```

depending of the type of the Info, i have to create one of the two different class i have: Demo1, Demo2, and then pass it in a function `handle` who will handle stuff. (this two class have the same characteristics). For now i made a `if/else if` on my enum and then i call 2 separate function for each... But these 2 function do the same thing... i wanted to create a template function who can take as parameter either one or the other class but i can't manage to create it...

```
if (Info == TYPE_1)
{
    Demo1 d1;
    handle1(d1);
}
else if (Info == TYPE_2)
{
    Demo2 d2;
    handle2(d2);
}
```

...

```
void handle1(Demo1 &d1)
{
   d1.getName();
}

void handle2(Demo2 &d2)
{
   d2.getName();
}
```

what are my option for a better codding style ?
may be create a **template class = Demo1 or Demo2**, and then pass this template class in parameter to a unique function `handle` ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are these types part of an inheritance hierarchy or completely unrelated types that happen to have the same interfaces (or at least a subset is the same)?

Comment: Is `info` a runtime value or compile time value ?

Comment: This part is inside a function `Parent::func()` of a Parent class `Parent`, and Demo1 and Demo2 are the child of `Parent`, who are created inside `Parent::func()`. Info is an enum priate of `Parent`. I don't know if there is a better way of encapsulation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear but I think you are looking for something as simple as this:

```
template<typename T>
  void handle(T &t)
{
   t.getName();
}
```

and use it as

```
handle(d1);
...
handle(d2);
```

instead of separate handle1 and handle2

Comment: Thanks, it is actually a really simple way to solve my issue ! I want to prototype this function `handle` in my class `Parrent`, as function class. can I do that, even if this function is also a template ?

Comment: template-function  can be a member of a class, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good candidate for polymorphism.

```
class DemoAbs {
  public:
    void getName() = 0;
};

class Demo1 public DemoAbs {
  public:
    void getName() { //impl here }
};

class Demo2 public DemoAbs {
  public:
    void getName() { //impl here }
}

DemoAbs *demo = 0;
if (Info == TYPE_1) {
  demo = new Demo1();
} else if(Info == TYPE_2) {
  demo = new Demo2();
}

handle(demo);

void handle(DemoAbs *demo) {
  demo->getName();
}
```

Hopefully that conveys the idea.